# how to run a jar file on the ubuntu 14.04 without stopping when i stopped the putty?

Tags: java, jar, ubuntu-14.04, executable

I am using ubuntu 14.04

I am running a jar file which should be collection a large amount of data for a few days.

I am running the jar file thought this command and it works fine.

```
java -jar xxx.jar
```

However when i close the putty, the process stopped. Is there a way for a jar file to run even when i close the putty?

Comment: [Tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) is installed by default (I think) on Ubuntu. Use that.

Comment: You can run it as system service using upstart or systemD scripts e.g. In that way the OS handles the running of the jar. Something like `sudo service yourApp start/stop/restart/satuts`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nohup to run the jar(any process) in background.

Use the following command in the putty session :

```
nohup java -jar xxx.jar &
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the nohup command. This command makes processes keep running despite closing terminal.

Run your jar with (in case you are in the right folder):

```
 nohup java -jar xxx.jar &
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to you use

```
nohup java -jar xxx.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

which redirects standard error & output of the command to /dev/null which means it's discarded. If you need the console output of this command then you can redirect it to any file as follows

```
nohup java -jar xxx.jar > output.log 2>&1 &
```